# Elliptic operator $d+d^*$

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-operators

We consider a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and the metric can induce the dual $d^*$ of $d$ by the formula:
$$
\int_M \langle\alpha, d\beta\rangle d{\text vol}_g = \int_M \langle d^*\alpha, \beta\rangle d{\text vol}_g
$$

I am a new graduate student, and one of my teacher mentioned in a class that $$d+d^*$$ is an elliptic operator. I am curious about this. I know elliptic operators in Euclidean spaces, but how to understand this? Could you tell me some references about this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Very quickly, write your operator in local coordinates and check that its [principal symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_of_a_differential_operator) $\sigma(p)$ is invertible for all $0\ne p\in T^*M$, then it is elliptic. To make this work, one has to consider $d+d^*$ acting simultaneously on forms of all degrees, $\Omega^\bullet(M) = \bigoplus_k \Omega^k(M)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on an Euclidean space, one is usually more familiar with the notion of a scalar elliptic operator (like the regular Laplacian which acts on functions) while in your situation, the operator is described in local coordinates as a vector operator and the solutions of $\Delta_g \omega = 0$ or $(d + d^{*})(\omega) = 0$ are described in local coordinates as solutions of a **system** of PDEs. Hence, one needs to generalize the (maybe) familiar notion of ellipticity to the case of a system of PDEs and then one can interpret your statement accordingly.

To do this invariantly on a manifold, one needs the notion of a partial differential operator between sections of vector bundles (which, in local coordinates, amounts to a system of partial differential operators) and to define when such an operator is elliptic. A good reference for the topic is Chapter 10 of Liviu I. Nicolaescu's [Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf).